# Asp .net MVC website Session instantly dies in MAC and iphone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, sitecore, session-cookies

We have an Asp .Net MVC website with Sitecore. The actual session value given in the web config is about 4 hrs. This is working fine in the PC. But the session instantly dies (about 1 or min) in iPhone and MAC.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It much looks [Sitecore Robot detection mechanism](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-does-Analytics-collection-work-and-why-it-might-not) sets session timeout to one minute based on your input.

To verify/disprove the assumption, you could temporary disable robot detection in **Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config**:

```
<setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots" value="true" />
```

In case experiment proves robot detection fault, do reach Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 0):

I will not suggest you to permanently disable the bot detection settings as it is kind of recommended in sitecore projects but alternatively what you can do, put `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` in the`<head><head>` section of the main layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />        
    @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```